# adding javascript file to wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am trying to add a JavaScript file to my WordPress site. The file is called social.js and contains all the scripts for my facebook, twitter etc buttons, and some JS for a floating menu that appears on scroll on the post pages.

I have uploaded the file to my parent themes js folder, but am not sure where to go from here.

Do i use:

```
wp_register_script()
```

Do I use:

```
wp_enqueue_script()
```

Do i use something like this:

```
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Should I combine all these JS files into one?

I am using twenty twelve child theme.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

James

Answer (score 0):

I'd be using:

wp_enqueue_script() in functions.php.

I have one in my theme that looks a bit like this:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'THEMENAME-navigation', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/navigation.js', array(), '20120206', true );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the first 2 or the 3rd option. 
Basically register_script assigns an wordpress internal name for your script, and you can register it as it depending on some other script. For ex you can say that your social.js depends on the query file to be loaded. 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script#Example_of_Automatic_Dependency_Loading

P.S. If you're using the wordpress default theme folders and you update your WP version the default theme folders also get updated in the process.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a child theme of TwentyTwelve then that's where your JS should be uploaded to rather than the parent theme.

Then add the following to your functions.php to correctly load the JS.

```
function wpse_load_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'wpse-html5', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/html5.js', array(), '1.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_load_scripts' );
```

OK so let's break down the code above.

You're running wpse_load_scripts() on the enqueue scripts action.

The first argument of wp_enqueue_script is the handle. A unique name for the file. html5 was a bit generic so I prefixed it with wpse-. Second argument is the path. Remember this is a child theme and that's where the JS should be so I'm using `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` instead of `get_template_directory_uri()`. Third is dependencies. I'm assuming no scripts are needed so I'm leaving it as a blank array. If you needed jQuery for the script to work you'd put 'jquery' inside the array. 4th we have the version number. And finally is whether this should load in the footer. true = yes / false = no.

Hope that helped and let me know if you need me to clarify anything.

Comment: Thank you Nathan for getting back to me, I have scoured the internet and not really found a clear enough answer for noobs. Your answer works great and fetches the file from my child theme - wpdoodles answer below also works but only if the file is in the parent theme. I take it this is because

Comment: get_template_directory only fetches files from parent theme? and get_stylesheet_directory gets it from child theme?

Comment: That's spot on James. `get_template_directory_uri` will return the URL to the parent theme and `get_stylesheet_directory_uri` returns the URL to the child theme. Anyway if this helped be sure to accept and upvote :)

Comment: Thanks nathan, I need a reputation to up vote so i guess I will have to help some people out on here to do that!